# Scanning barcode in images in flutter

Tags: flutter

Is there any package to scan a barcodes and qrcodes from images in flutter. What I want is that when scanning the barcode from the image it should also return the type of barcode.

I have tried scan and FLutterBarcodeScan but they do not return the type of barcode that is scanned from image.

Comment: REFER [PACKAGE](https://pub.dev/packages/simple_barcode_scanner). ALSO [THIS PACKAGE](https://pub.dev/packages/ai_barcode_scanner).

Comment: there is no barcode scanning from the image in the Ai barcode scanner

Comment: you can use ml kit barcode scanner package https://pub.dev/packages/google_mlkit_barcode_scanning .

Answer (score 0):

Use This package:- [Google ML kit barcode Scanning](https://pub.dev/packages/google_mlkit_barcode_scanning)

For Camera I have used this package:- [Camera](https://pub.dev/packages/camera)

You have to add android and iOS permission and configuration. For this you have checkout package readme.md file.

In this demo you user can select barcode from gallery of capture from camera.

**Note:- In this demo not added iOS configuration.**

Github Link:- [Google ML kit barcode Scanning demo](https://github.com/jeeldev9/google_ml_kit_barcode_scanning_demo.git)

Output:-
[Click here to see output](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aJaggYOZ5wGH_AjjiE0pOoxnYYnKgXdT/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @asliddin review this answer

Comment: the demo was a little unclear, to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**
I found this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/fl_mlkit_scanning/example). That is what I wanted. The usage is explained clearly and easy to use.